# java is not pure OOP

Tags: java

As we know java is not pure object orientd programming because of primitive types (int,char etc..)
is there any thing else due to that we can say java is not pure object oriented programming language.

Think static variable and multiple inheritence also the points for not being Java pure object oriented Programming language.

Comment: I recommend editing this so there's an actual question in your question; otherwise, this is going to get closed, fast.

Comment: I can't correct you, since I can't edit others' posts yet.  Until then, please take care in typing your questions without spelling mistakes, with correct grammar and capitalization, and using full words.  I'm not sure what "resp" is.

Comment: Also, accept answers for your questions. You're at 0%.

Comment: I've been thinking about this issue lately--if your primitives are never passed to a public interface, they really aren't "Un-OO"--you can end up with a pure OO interface (which is the important part).  If I was trying to go "Pure", I'd also never pass a collection or other library class since you can't modify those objects with business logic in Java making them pretty much as OO un-pure as primitive types.  I kinda would have liked to looked into some of these concepts.  I wish there was a way to move a question off the main SO board and into a "Let's BS about it" area when it's closed...

Answer (score 3):

There are some arguments from at least one Java guru that [static is not good](http://gbracha.blogspot.com/2008/02/cutting-out-static.html), though Bracha never actually makes a value judgement on whether they are pure OO or not (outside of homework and job interviews, it's not a very useful discussion, instead engineers work on whether something has good consequences)