# If Java is a pure OOP Language, then what about primitive data types?

Tags: java, oop, primitive-types

Everything in Java is an object (as what is said). Then what are primitive data types?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990981/java-is-not-pure-oop

Comment: I've heard that about Smalltalk, never about Java.

Comment: Is there a meaningful question in there somewhere?

Comment: *"Every thing in JAVA is an object (as what is said)..."* Said by whom? They're wrong. Some things in Java are objects, other things are not. Primitives are not.

Comment: I can do that too!! *"Pigs fly (as what is said).  Then why won't my pig take off?"*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read an official description of the Java language:

http://java.sun.com/docs/white/langenv/Object.doc.html

you will find that it says:

> With the exception of its primitive
>   data types, everything in Java is an
>   object, and even the primitive types
>   can be encapsulated within objects if
>   the need arises.

Comment: Note that "everything" here means "every data type". In other languages this "everything" would imply many other things, including control structures, for example.

Answer (score 4):

I've yet to find a strict, useful definition of what "pure OOP" means that people can agree on.

Lacking such a definition we can't really say if **any** language is pure OOP.

Regarding "Everything in Java is an object": that's simply not true. There are many things in Java that are not objects. Variables are not object (they are references), primitive values are not objects, methods are not objects (they don't have properties), ...

Answer (score 0):

Primitive datatypes are those which are not objects : `int`, `long`, `boolean`, ...

*(Well, not everything is an object, in Java)*